# make textarea to fit the rest of space

Tags: html, css, grid

I need my textarea `wrapctxt` to always fit the rest of space below `wrapctop` (i.e. to the bottom of `wrapc`).

```css
.panelb{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 130px 34% auto;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapa{
  background:gold;
}
.wrapb{
  background:silver;
}
.wrapc{
  background:lightseagreen;
}
.wrapctop{
  background:lightblue;
  padding:9px;
}
.wrapctxt{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:gold;
  padding:0;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='panelb'>
  <div class='wrapa'>wrapa</div>
  <div class='wrapb'>wrapb</div>
  <div class='wrapc'>
    <div class='wrapctop'>wrapctop</div>
    <textarea class='wrapctxt'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

The amount of text inside `wrapctop` is variable, so its height is unknown.  How can I make the `wrapctxt` fit exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panelb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 130px 34% auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapa {
  background: gold;
}

.wrapb {
  background: silver;
}

.wrapc {
  background: lightseagreen;
}

.wrapctop {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 9px;
}

.wrapctxt {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: gold;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 36px);
}
```

```html
<div class='panelb'>
  <div class='wrapa'>wrapa</div>
  <div class='wrapb'>wrapb</div>
  <div class='wrapc'>
    <div class='wrapctop'>wrapctop</div>
    <textarea class='wrapctxt'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to make the textarea to fit the free space if it's empty?

Comment: and how to stop increasing its height if it already fitts the rest of space. pls, read my question again.

Comment: In that case no js required. Add `height: 100vh;` to `.wrapctxt` and you will fill the container with the text area.

Comment: Let me edit my snippet. I missed the last point :) Giv me a few min @puerto

Comment: `100vh` doesn't work, of course, that is entire viewport height.

Comment: no problem, take your time. I'll be back in 20 min.

Comment: I've made a few changes now. Let me know if it helps or we can try again. I hope we are on the same page now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178096/discussion-between-thebrownkid-and-puerto).

Comment: And what if `wrapctop` height is 50px? There is the following note in my post: `ammount of text inside wrapctop is a variable so its height is changable.`

Comment: It's simple in that case. Instead of giving padding, set a height for `wrapctop`. For eg: If you set `height: 40px` to `wrapctop` then `wrapctxt` will be `height: calc(100% - 40px);`

Comment: Does it answer all your questions @puerto?

Comment: hmmm... I wanted something slightly different, but... why not, It works. Thanks a lot.